# WPF ComboBox: how to set focus on it's togglebutton

Tags: wpf, combobox, focus, styles, controltemplate

I'm trying to get a `ComboBox` to match a visual design, so its `ToggleButton` has a blue border when the `ComboBox` has focus. I can't figure out how to do this and can't find an example.

When the `ComboBox` gets focus, the `TextBox` inside gets the dashed focus visual. How do I pass the `ComboBox` focus state down to the `ToggleButton`, so that it's blue border style is turned on?

Here is my `ComboBox` template:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxCT" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Grid x:Name="gLayoutRoot"
        Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}" 
        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" 
        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" 
        MinWidth="{TemplateBinding MinWidth}" 
        MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}" 
        MaxWidth="{TemplateBinding MaxWidth}" 
        MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxHeight}" 
        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}">
        <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton" 
            Grid.Column="2" 
            Focusable="false"
            IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
            ClickMode="Press" 
            Style="{DynamicResource ComboBoxToggleStyle}" 
            />
        <AccessText x:Name="ContentSite" 
            Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxAccessTextStyle}" 
            Text="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" 
            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
            Style="{x:Null}" 
            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" 
            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" 
            Margin="2,3,17,2"
            Focusable="True" 
            Background="{DynamicResource InnerBgLight}"
            Visibility="Hidden"
            IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}">
            <TextBox.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Border x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </TextBox.Template>
        </TextBox>
        <Popup x:Name="Popup"
            Placement="Bottom"
            IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
            AllowsTransparency="True" 
            Focusable="False"
            PopupAnimation="Slide">
                <Grid x:Name="DropDown"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True"                
                    MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                    MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                        <Border x:Name="OuterBorder"
                            Style="{DynamicResource OuterBorderBottomRestStyle}"
                            Background="{DynamicResource InnerBorder}">
                            <Border x:Name="InnerBorder" 
                                Style="{DynamicResource InnerBottomBorderStyle}">
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="scvCbxItems" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                    <StackPanel x:Name="spCbxItemsPanel" IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                </Grid>
            </Popup>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                <Setter TargetName="InnerBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource FgDisabledBrush}"/>
                <Setter Property="OpacityMask" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{DynamicResource OuterBgDisabledOpacityMask}"/>
            </Trigger>  
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

And here's my `ToggleButton` template:

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleCT" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Border x:Name="OuterBorder" 
        Style="{DynamicResource OuterBorderTopRestStyle}">
        <Border x:Name="InnerBorder" 
            Style="{DynamicResource InnerTopBorderStyle}">
                <Path x:Name="Arrow" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Margin="5"
                    Fill="{DynamicResource FgBrush}"
                    Data="{DynamicResource DownArrowGeometry}"/>
        </Border>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{DynamicResource OuterBorderTopSelectStyle}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="OpacityMask" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{DynamicResource OuterBgDisabledOpacityMask}"/>
            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="{DynamicResource FgDisabledBrush}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{DynamicResource OuterBorderTopSelectStyle}"/>
            <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="InnerBorder" Value="{DynamicResource InnerBorderTopFocusStyle}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <!--<Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">-->
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsFocused}">
            <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{DynamicResource OuterBorderBottomFocusStyle}"/>
            <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="InnerBorder" Value="{DynamicResource InnerBorderTopFocusStyle}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

</ControlTemplate>
```

As you can see I try to bind to the `ComboBox`'s focus state, but that doesn't work inside the `Trigger`.

Any help appreciated. Sorry for the noob question. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to have a binding to the Templated Parent's IsFocused. Note: Mode=OneWay is important since IsFocused is read only. You could do something like this:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFocused, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWay}" Value="True">
   <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{DynamicResource OuterBorderBottomFocusStyle}"/>
   <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="InnerBorder" Value="{DynamicResource InnerBorderTopFocusStyle}"/>
</DataTrigger >
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to customize or chose a FocusVisualStyle:
See here:
[MSDN: Styling for Focus in Controls, and FocusVisualStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613567.aspx)

I think the blue one you want to have is from some original windows theme, maybe it's contained in this download [Default WPF Themes](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=wpfsamples&DownloadId=7812) from [Microsoft WPF Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpfsamples#themes).

Comment: The focusvisual only draws the box around the textbox inside the control. I want to style the togglebutton so the entire thing is highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

You have set `Focusable=False` for your ToggleButton in the ControlTemplate, so when it receives the focus, it passes it down to the next inner focusable UIElement.
If you remove that, your ToggleButton should get the focus instead of the TextBox.

Comment: Doing this causes the combobox to get focus twice--you get the dashed line around the combobox, then down into the togglebutton. You tab twice and stay on the combobox.

Comment: UISpy doesn't register going down to the togglebutton--it just stays on 'combobox' when you tab to it both times. I want a single focus event for the combobox. The textbox needs to receive focus as well for when the combobox is editable.

Answer (score 0):

Binding to the templated parent's `IsFocused` prperty do not work when you set the `ComboBox.IsEditable` property to `True`. Instead you can use `IsKeyboardFocusWithin`, check the following:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsKeyboardFocusWithin, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWay}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="{DynamicResource MainColorLight}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Border" Value="{DynamicResource MainColorLight}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Border2" Value="{DynamicResource MainColorLight}" />
    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="White" />
</DataTrigger >
```